# Ignoring the base folder name when importing a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, package

I have a python library with the structure:

```
my_project <-- Base folder
 |
 +-- my_project <-- Source folder
 |    
 +----- my_project.py <-- contains class MyProject
 |   
 +----- __init__.py
 |
 +-- tests
```

Currently I have to reference the project as:

```py
from my_project.my_project import MyProject
```

My setup.cfg:

```
[options]
packages = find:

[options.packages.find]
include = my_project
```

What I can't figure out is how to change the `import`s so that it only requires a single reference to `my_project`. Looked everywhere and tried multiple combinations including changing `my_project` to `src`.

```py
from my_project import MyProject
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're confusing your base folder with the source folder.
Currently, you're using two references to `my_project` but neither reference points to the base folder.

```py
from my_project.my_project import MyProject
        ^           ^
the source folder   |
                    |
               the my_project.py file
```

You're not referencing the base folder anywhere. This *is* how you should reference modules and classes in your code in the first place, there's nothing wrong with this.

Comment: OK. I see what you're saying and makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: The confusion I had, which as explained I was including the base folder. Was that I needed to move the my_project.py up one level, out of my_project directory. On the setup.cfg I could then add py_modules = my_project. I also changed the my_project folder to src.